# My IP is being blocked in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, ip, windows-firewall

My IP from my home is being blocked by my server (Windows Server 2012 R2).  Where can I find and turn off this block?  I believe it happened while working on a custom IP protocol for a program I was working on.

I have confirmed this with tracert as it traces right up to the router the server is connected to.

I browsed windows firewall settings and cannot seem to find it.  I am very convinced this is a dynamic block.  Where can I find this list of blocked IPs and remove the problematic one?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It was not my program but RDP that was the culprit using RDPGuard (something the hosting provider had installed).  I found my IP there and whitelisted it.